# MySQL DELETE statement not recognizing an empid number from PHP $id variable

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to allow DELETE-ion of employees in a database. I have stored the query string being passed into a variable named $id. When I run my SQL DELETE statement, it echo's out but is not echo-ing or recognizing the $id variable I instantiated. Any ideas?

PHP

```
//QUERY STRING
"<td><a href='delete.php?id=" . $row['empid']  . "'>Delete</a></td>" .

//ID VARIABLE
 $id = (isset($REQUEST['id']) ? $_REQUEST['id'] : '');
```

SQL

```
//SQL STATEMENT
$sql = "DELETE FROM employees WHERE empid= '" . $id . "';";

//WHAT ECHOS OUT IS BELOW
echo($sql);

//RUN SQL Command
mysqli_query($connect,$sql) or die(mysql_error());
print("User " . $id . " deleted from the database.");
print("Return to <a href='index.php'>Return To Main Page</a>");
```

DELETE FROM employees WHERE empid= '';

When I click delete from the index.php the employee I tried to delete is still there.

Comment: Are any errors being thrown? if so what ones

Comment: I don't see where and how you executed the query and which api is used. All you did was echo the query.

Comment: @Issac No there are no errors being thrown.

Comment: @Funk Forty Niner, Just added it, thank you.

Comment: now you edited; that error function won't work with the mysqli_ api. I think the array is empty.

Comment: can you share detailed code

Comment: Oh I see now; it's an undefined index issue here. Error reporting would have told you about it.

Comment: I am new to MySQL, how do I ensure I have error reporting 'on'?

Comment: just add these lines in php code  " error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');"

Comment: Thank you @Parikshit Sharma!

Comment: Also this before you connect to the database: `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL);` See http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-driver.report-mode.php

Comment: You should delete data only in a POST request, not in a GET request. Keep in mind search engines will follow links to GET requests. Get ready for all your data to be deleted by Google as it indexes your site!

Comment: You also have an SQL injection vulnerability in your code (like most new programmers). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: @Bill Karwin, this is really good to know, I will change to POST! I appreciate you imparting extra knowledge, I will definitely remember this.

Comment: I inserted the Error checking code mentioned to me above and now I am receiving a ton of errors when I run the code:  Uncaught exception 'mysqli_sql_exception' with message 'No index used in query/prepared statement............ I am looking into  this now...Rabbit Hole for new programmers lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change this line

`$id = (isset($REQUEST['id']) ? $_REQUEST['id'] : '');`

to

`$id = (isset($_REQUEST['id']) ? $_REQUEST['id'] : '');`

Comment: Yep that was it. Thanks Simon!